# My room is always covered with tiny fibers but I can't figure out the source

Tags: cleaning, dust, vacuum, vacuum-cleaner

My room is always covered with these tiny fibers, no matter how often I vacuum it. I even bought an air purifier with a HEPA filter that runs 24x7 but it's not helping at all. These pictures were taken around 48 hours after vacuuming the room and then wiping down every surface. Oddly, all other rooms in the house are relatively dust-free. Please help me figure out what it is, where it's coming from, and what I can do to get rid of it.

Thanks.

[image: What is this?]

[image: A zoomed in picture]

[image: Ruler for scale]

Comment: Do you have s fireplace

Comment: Possible contamination in HVAC duct

Comment: Do you have a lot of clothing / equipment / bags that use Velcro closures instead of zippers?

Comment: @RohitGupta No, I don't have a fireplace

Comment: @MTA No, I don't have anything with a velcro.

Comment: @Ruskes I don't have an HVAC system, just a portable air purifier.

Comment: what type of filter is in your air purifier? Do you have and animal in there? Have you shaved or gotten a haircut recently? Is there a window that is open, and what is outside of that window?  Do you keep the door closed?  Is there normally a draft into or out of the room?

Comment: Do you have clothing or shoes that could have dark fibers that you wear often?

Comment: What else is in the room?

Comment: What do you own that is this color and made of fiber?

Comment: My air purifier has 3 filters in total, including a HEPA filter (green). I don't have any pets. I keep my door closed but I do leave one of my windows open sometimes. Thre's a backyard outside my window covered with a bit of grass and soil. @RMDman

Comment: Most of my clothes are black in color but it seems to me that these fibers are uniformly distributed across my room. Now that I think about it, though, I think my clothes might be the source of these fibers. @RMDman

Comment: And I think vacuuming doesn't help because the dust is somehow leaking out

Answer (score 3):

I'm late with my comment, maybe your problem is already solved but just in case I want to share this since I notice it hasn't been mentioned already.

××× This unfortunately looks like it could be asbestos dust. ×××

We live in an old building on top of what used to be a workshop, with the garage as a part of our living space, and have just recently discovered these fibres been pouring in to our apparent. So much that I've had really bad respiratory issues.
Over a year or so I've experienced asthmatic symptoms, gradually getting worse. At first I related it to post-covid sensitivity, I never had any kind of problem like this before. A couple of weeks ago, I started to cough extremely much on two occasions and spitted out tons of these from my airways. I also found fibres stuck in the back of my throat and sinuses.

Afterwards I researched it thoroughly, and we moved out last weekend. Despite it being Christmas week.

Basically our (rental) house is falling apart. It's partly built and rebuilt in the 70's. Holes in asbestos insulated ventilation pipes inside the house, asbestos cement wallpaint, asbestos slab attic insulation, asbestos board ceiling and pretty much everything is cracking up, releasing big amounts of fibre. Different types for various materials.

You should definitely make sure if this is the case for you too, it's really dangerous breathing asbestos particles in and known to cause cancer and other respiratory illnesses. It's completely banned from the market since the 80's here in Sweden, and forbidden worldwide to use in any construction at all today.

Hope you are doing well, and that this information can help someone else too.

[image: Tiny hair like fibres]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Pieces of old asbestos cement roof falling off]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are most likely from the filtering you have in the return air for the HVAC system.  If your room is the only one getting the fibers, check the service duct in the room.  There are filters made to install at the grate of these ducts. it could be the source.  OR finally,  you may have a shedding blanket.

Comment: I don't have an HVAC system installed and all my blankets/sheets are white.